# sql left join with where confusion

Tags: sql

This is my current sql query

```
SELECT 
  urls.short, 
  urls.long, 
  urls.user, 
  dates.date AS date, 
  COUNT(views.short) AS views, 
  SUM(views.money) AS money 
FROM dates 
LEFT JOIN views ON dates.date = views.date
LEFT JOIN urls ON views.short = urls.short
WHERE urls.user='test'
GROUP BY dates.date, views.date
LIMIT 0, 20
```

It show results something like this :

> 2011-02-08    test    test        1   0.003
>
> 2011-02-09    test    test        6   0.016

But when i remove

```
WHERE urls.user='test'
```

I get

> 2011-02-05                0
>
> 2011-02-06                0
>
> 2011-02-07    44kc    http://google.com       27  0.031
>
> 2011-02-08    44kc    http://google.com       15  0.045
>
> 2011-02-09    test    test        12  0.032
>
> 2011-02-10                0

so finally i want to get the second query result using first query(to show 0 ,when there are nothing available).
So whats the solution?

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you might want to consider

```
LEFT JOIN urls ON views.short = urls.short AND urls.user='test'
```

Comment: This is correct. The LEFT JOIN was working fine but the WHERE clause was then restricting rows based on a column that was brought in from the optionally joined table thus excluding the non-joined rows. Moving the logic to the join condition fixes this.